# Parser written in Haskell not working as intended

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I was playing around with Haskell's `parsec` library. I was trying to parse a hexadecimal string of the form `"#x[0-9A-Fa-f]*"` into an integer. This the code I thought would work:

```hs
module Main where

import Control.Monad
import Numeric
import System.Environment
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec hiding (spaces)

parseHex :: Parser Integer
parseHex = do
  string "#x"
  x <- many1 hexDigit
  return (fst (head (readHex x)))

testHex :: String -> String
testHex input = case parse parseHex "lisp" input of
  Left err -> "Does not match " ++ show err
  Right val -> "Matched" ++ show val

main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  putStrLn (testHex (head args))
```

And then I tried testing the `testHex` function in Haskell's repl:

```
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( src/Main.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> testHex "#xcafebeef"
"Matched3405692655"
*Main> testHex "#xnothx"
"Does not match \"lisp\" (line 1, column 3):\nunexpected \"n\"\nexpecting hexadecimal digit"
*Main> testHex "#xcafexbeef"
"Matched51966"
```

The first and second try work as intended. But in the third one, the string is matching upto the invalid character. I do not want the  parser to do this, but rather not match if any digit in the string is not a valid string. Why is this happening, and how do if fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Usually a parser like this will be embedded in a larger parser, like one that will then expect there to be some plus signs or parentheses or like a semicolon or something after the hex number. In that situation, you *do* want the hex-number parser to succeed and stop at the first invalid character -- to let the rest of the parser it's contained in have its go at whatever follows.

Comment: @DanielWagner That actually makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to place [`eof`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:eof) at the end.

```
parseHex :: Parser Integer
parseHex = do
  string "#x"
  x <- many1 hexDigit
  eof
  return (fst (head (readHex x)))
```

Alternatively, you can compose it with `eof` where you use it if you want to reuse `parseHex` in other places.

```
testHex :: String -> String
testHex input = case parse (parseHex <* eof) "lisp" input of
  Left err -> "Does not match " ++ show err
  Right val -> "Matched" ++ show val
```